# WebSockets sends fragments of cookies

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, cookies, websocket

Hei!

I have simple single web page javascript application, running on ASP MVC. My js app communicate with console c# server using WebSockets (Alchemy WebSockets on server side). Everything works fine, but...

When client (tested with latest Chrome, FF, Opera) connects to a server, server receives several messages, which wasnt programmaticaly send from client (send method wasnt called). I have found out that these are random fragments of current cookies stored in client browser. This problem also disappears after a cookie cache is cleared, but since it contains some data, problem appears again.

Has anybody also reached the same or similar strange behavior? Does anyone know to solve that?